# Flexvol: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "elasticsearch-backup", Refer to the .staticx.prog(8)

Tags: kubernetes

I have a stateful set with 3 replicas. The pods mount the following flexvol

```yaml
      volumes:
        - flexVolume:
            driver: microsoft.com/smb
            options:
              mountoptions: 'vers=3.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,,uid=1000,gid=1000'
              source: //sc.intra/data/backup/K8s/optimize
            secretRef:
              name: smbcreds-optimize
          name: elasticsearch-backup
```

While the mount of the flexvol works fine on 2 of the pods, on one it does not work

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "elasticsearch-backup" : mount command failed, status: Failure, reason: Failed to mount device at /var/lib/kubelet/pods/1cb0afbf-43a8-4ca5-9282-d8a6130a1e02/volumes/microsoft.com~smb/elasticsearch-backup, user:XXXX, //sc.intra/data/backup/K8s/optimize, error log:Refer to the .staticx.prog(8) manual page (e.g. man .staticx.prog)
```

In the logs of the affected node, I can see this

```
kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

Any suggestion what could cause this problem and how I can debug/fix it?

Comment: Error code 13 usually means 'permission denied'

Comment: Yes I know, unfortunatley it still does not explain why it should work on 2 of 3 nodes. It's the same smb endpoint and same user for authentication

Comment: It could be wrong permissions on the mount point, it could be the node itself not having permissions to access the share.